# Visual Studio SSRS - DataElementOutput hide in csv

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that is made up of a table of date, and then the last row is a total/summary row where the dat ais being summed.

When you export in pdf the data shows fine, when you export in csv the summary rows have been tunred into columns.

I know there is a DataElementOutput option but can i put an expression there to say only hide when the file format is csv?

Comment: Try to set the `hide` property based on an expression like `=(Globals!RenderFormat.Name="CSV")`.

Comment: Just tried that but the columns are still there, thanks though

Comment: What happens when you export to Word? CSV is "just" a text file that can be opened in Excel, but Word, as with PDF can be used with formatting.